# Create new columns in pandas data frame based on existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary as follows:

```
ref_dict = {
"Company1" :["C1_Dev1","C1_Dev2","C1_Dev3","C1_Dev4","C1_Dev5",],
"Company2" :["C2_Dev1","C2_Dev2","C2_Dev3","C2_Dev4","C2_Dev5",],
"Company3" :["C3_Dev1","C3_Dev2","C3_Dev3","C3_Dev4","C3_Dev5",],
 }
```

I have a Pandas data frame called **df** whose one of the columns looks like this:

```
    DESC_DETAIL
0   Probably task Company2 C2_Dev5
1   File system C3_Dev1
2   Weather subcutaneous Company2
3   Company1 Travesty C1_Dev3
4   Does not match anything 
...........
```

My goal is to add two extra columns to this data frame and name the columns, **COMPANY** and **DEVICE**. The value in each row of the **COMPANY** column will be either be the company key in the dictionary if it exists in the **DESC_DETAIL** column or if the corresponding device exists in the **DESC_DETAIL** column. The value in the **DEVICE** column will simply be the device string in the **DESC_DETAIL** column. If no match is found, the corresponding row is empty. Hence the final output will look like this:

```
     DESC_DETAIL                        COMPANY         DEVICE
 0   Probably task Company2 C2_Dev5     Company2        C2_Dev5
 1   File system C3_Dev1                Company3        C3_Dev1
 2   Weather subcutaneous Company2      Company2        NaN
 3   Company1 Travesty C1_Dev3          Company1        C1_Dev3
 4   Does not match anything            NaN             NaN
```

My attempt:

```
for key, value in ref_dict.items():
    df['COMPANY'] = df.apply(lambda row: key if row['DESC_DETAIL'].isin(key) else Nan, axis=1)
```

This is obviously just wrong and does not work. How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract values with `str.extract` using a regex pattern:

```
import re

s = pd.Series(ref_dict).explode()

# extract company
df['COMPANY'] = df['DESC_DETAIL'].str.extract(
    f"({'|'.join(s.index.unique())})", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# extract device
df['DEVICE'] = df['DESC_DETAIL'].str.extract(
    f"({'|'.join(s)})", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# fill missing company values based on device
df['COMPANY'] = df['COMPANY'].fillna(
    df['DEVICE'].str.lower().map(dict(zip(s.str.lower(), s.index))))

df
```

Output:

```
                      DESC_DETAIL   COMPANY   DEVICE
0  Probably task Company2 C2_Dev5  Company2  C2_Dev5
1             File system C3_Dev1  Company3  C3_Dev1
2   Weather subcutaneous Company2  Company2      NaN
3       Company1 Travesty C1_Dev3  Company1  C1_Dev3
4         Does not match anything       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: @perl..the extract device line gives me an error saying..ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

Comment: @Amistad Can you share your data? Running without any problem on your sample

Comment: @perl..i figured the issue but now this is not working since the string is upper and lower at various places..How do I make the search case insensitive

Comment: @Amistad Just pass `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to `str.extract`

Comment: Edited my answer to make it case-insensitive

Comment: @Perl..this is perfect..thank you so much..The only time this fails is if the search string has brackets like "Envoy 6F (XB)"..then i get the value error which I pasted in the first comment.

Comment: also the last step now does not work because the zip function still looks for the case sensitive values..

Comment: @Amistad OK, so re that `zip` function, we can lowercase everything before the lookup. I've edited my answer with that change

Comment: To search for strings containing brackets, you need to escape them with \, e.g. `"\(C1_Dev5\)"` (you also need to escape `|` and other special symbols in regex)

Comment: Thank you so much...you have been awesome..everything works now !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a device to company dictionary as well and you can build it from the `ref_dict` easily as below:

```
dev_to_company_dict = {v:l[0] for l in zip(ref_dict.keys(), ref_dict.values()) for v in l[1]}
```

Then it is easy to do this:

```
df['COMPANY'] = df['DESC_DETAIL'].apply(lambda det : ''.join(set(re.split("\\s+", det)).intersection(ref_dict.keys())))
df['COMPANY'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['DEVICE'] = df['DESC_DETAIL'].apply(lambda det : ''.join(set(re.split("\\s+", det)).intersection(dev_to_company_dict.keys())))
df['DEVICE'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['COMPANY'] = df['COMPANY'].fillna(df['DEVICE'].map(dev_to_company_dict))
```

Output:

```
                       DESC_DETAIL   COMPANY     DEVICE
0   Probably task Company2 C2_Dev5  Company2    C2_Dev5
1   File system C3_Dev1             Company3    C3_Dev1
2   Weather subcutaneous Company2   Company2        NaN
3   Company1 Travesty C1_Dev3       Company1    C1_Dev3
4   Does not match anything              NaN        NaN
```

Comment: @SomeDude..how do i make the search case insensitive

Comment: Can be done, but going to be ugly. @perl's is better.